# How to draw a bootstrap progress bar dynamically from two values

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

i got two values last month views: 10000
This month views : 500000 .

I want to draw a progress bar from this two values 
What formulae should i use to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Google Bar Charts for achieving this, please see below example :

```js
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Views'],
          ['2017', 10000],
          ['2018', 500000 ]
        ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Website Performance',
            subtitle: 'Views per year',
          },
          bars: 'vertical' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   </head>
  <body>
    <div id="barchart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Check more documentation on here :
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

Answer (score 0):

Google charts answer is more efficient in my point of view as well. but if you want to show bootstrap progress bar, you can do that with two ways. if you already generated the two values you can just echo it directly inside the progress bar styles, as follows

```
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" id="bar_1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?php echo $value; ?>%">
      <span class="sr-only"><?php echo $value; ?>% Complete</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But you didn't generated it in this page and you want to generated it in the server site you can use simple javascript function using ajax to overcome that.

```
   <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" id="bar_1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:10%">
            <span class="sr-only"><span id="value_1">70</span>% Complete</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
           url: "your_php_file.php", 
           success: function (responseText) {
             $("#bar_1").css('width', responseText+'%');
             $("#value_1").html(responseText);
           }
        });
     });
    </script>
```

As you can see you can calculate your progress value in your_php_file.php and echo it. make sure you call jquery library as well.